# Can not assign a value of type "Any" to type "String?" Swift 3 (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift

I want to take the token from the server and then assign it to the token variable so I can pass it as a headers in my .post request method.

```
var token = ["X-Auth-Token": ""]
```

Assigning process

```
token["X-Auth-Token"] = response.result.value!
```

After doing this I get the error

> can not assign value of type "Any" to type "String?"

How do I bypass or fix this?

Full class:

```
import Alamofire
import UIKit

class InitialViewController: UIViewController {
    let url = "https://api.sis.kemoke.net/auth/login"
    var parameters = ["email": "", "password": ""]
    var token = ["X-Auth-Token": ""]

    // Parameters textfields
    @IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField?
    @IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField?

    // A method for the login button
    @IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        parameters["email"] = email?.text
        parameters["password"] = password?.text
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: nil).responseJSON {
            (response) in
            print(response.result.value!)
            token["X-Auth-Token"] = response.result.value!
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest this approach:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: nil).responseJSON {
    (response) in
    if let tokenString = response.result.value as? String {
        token["X-Auth-Token"] = tokenString
    }
}
```

By using `if let tokenString = response.result.value as? String` you will check if `response.result.value` is a String before trying to cast it to String.

Always try to **avoid explictly unwraping an optional** like this:

```
token["X-Auth-Token"] = response.result.value as! String
```

If `response.result.value` is, for some reason, not a String your app would crash.
The main purpose of optionals is to protect you from crashes like that.

Comment: FYI - the `print` statement will cause a crash. Move it inside the `if let`.

Comment: Thanks. I removed `print` from the answer as it's not that really important for the implementation.

Answer (score -2):

Cast to string if it's a string

```
@IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    parameters["email"] = email?.text
    parameters["password"] = password?.text
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: nil).responseJSON {
        (response) in
        print(response.result.value?)
        token["X-Auth-Token"] = response.result.value as? String
    }
```

Comment: Don't do this. This will crash if `response.result.value` is `nil` or if it's not really a `String`.

Comment: also we can  use "guard" or "if let"

Comment: The funny part is that he is unwrapping the optional in the `print` statement, and then using the optional type while assigning the value...this doesn't make sense, if it crashes, it would crash in the print statement